# Why it is not Possible to call textBox1_KeyPress() event from some Button Click event.?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("called btn 0 click..");
        KeyPressEventArgs e0 = new KeyPressEventArgs('0');
        textBox1_KeyPress(sender, e0);
    }
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("called txtbox_keypress event...");
    }    
}
```

Am sorry if this is a silly question,I have just started to learn windows forms, I still find material on the internet confusing.I want to implement calculator. So when number button is pressed it should be filled in textbox. So I thought calling textBox1_keypress() event from  button click event would work??? but its not working,

I can manually write the logic in button click event to fill text in text box but if i do so, i have to do the same thing in button1_KeyPress event too. so it would be duplication of code right??...so i thought solution was to call textBox1_KeyPress() event from both button click event and button key press event...but its not working .So what should i do???..is there any other approach which should i follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so it would be duplication of code right??

Yes, it would be. So you can do

```
private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonMethod(e);
}
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    CommonMethod(e);
}

private void CommonMethod(EventArgs e)
{
    //Your logic here.
}
```

Comment: If he wants to use different parts of `EventArgs` and `KeyPressEventArgs`, it doesn't make sense to tie the two together like that.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBox `KeyPress` event handler (`textBox1_KeyPress`) is called *after* the user presses a key. The `KeyPressEventArgs` parameter includes information such as what key was pressed. So calling it from your `btn0_Click` method isn't going to set the text for the TextBox.

Rather, you want to (probably) append whatever number the user pressed to the text already present in the TextBox. Something like

```
private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += "0";
}
```

might be closer to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to tie the events together like that.
A key-press is one thing, handled in one way.
A button click is something totally different and should be handled as such.

The basic reason is this,
The button doesn't know what number it is, you need to tell it that.
A key-press on the other hand, knows what number was pressed.

If you REALLY want to, for some reason, you [could use SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to trigger your key-press event in a round-about way, from the button.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the logic in an extra function like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumberLogic(0),
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // I don't know right now if e contains the key pressed. If not replace by the correct argument
        NumberLogic(Convert.ToInt32(e));
    }

    void NumberLogic(int numberPressed){
        MessageBox.Show("Button " + numberPressed.ToString() + " pressed.");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you to use an Tag Property of the Buttons. Put in it the value of each button in Design mode or in Constructor, create one button event handler for all buttons and use Tag value:

Constructor:

```
        button1.Tag = 1;
        button2.Tag = 2;

        button1.Click += buttons_Click;
        button2.Click += buttons_Click;
```

Event hadler:

```
private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
    }
```